# Implementing non-memory Identity Server storage - is it okay if the SubjectId is the acutal Id of a database table?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

Compared to a large unique number, which is the subjectId by default, is it very bad if I simply store the primary key column in there? For some users, that value will be `1`, for others, `9480`, but hardly will it ever be something as huge as the default subjectId. It's an auto-identity column, so you can imagine in what way it behaves.

If it's bad-practice, please explain why, as I don't see a reason for having an additional column filled with these attributes. The token should be protected by a signature, so they can't abuse this in any way?

Comment: Primary Keys are made for indexing. Primary keys are made to be unique numbers. Primary keys are made to be static, once assigned. If you need a Idenitifier, Index, Identifier for a Checkbox, or something similar nothing beats using a existing PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SubjectIDTypes):

> A Subject Identifier is a locally unique and never reassigned
>   identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be
>   consumed by the Client.

So the Id of a user suits perfect, which is also the default value used for `sub`. And you are free on how to implement the Id (e.g. Guid or int). But there is more in the specification:

> Two Subject Identifier types are defined by this specification:
>
> public
>
> This provides the same sub (subject) value to all Clients. It is the default if the provider has no subject_types_supported element
>   in its discovery document.
>
> pairwise
>
> This provides a different sub value to each Client, so as not to enable Clients to correlate the End-User's activities without
>   permission.

IdentityServer uses `public` subs by default. If you are concerned about privacy you can switch to `pairwise` subs.

However, at the moment client specific subjects are not supported by IdentityServer. This seems to be planned for a future release, as [discussed here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1557).

Comment: I'm a little confused by their definition for public: '_This provides the **same** sub (subject) value to all Clients._' - what do they mean by same? SubjectId is always different, or client there refers to the end-user? Each user has their own subjectId, they are never the same.

Because I can't understand the definition of public, I can't even begin to fathom what pariwise's idea is. If you could clarify that, it'd be great!

Comment: @SpiritBob This is from a client (application) perspective. Public means that every client receives the same sub for this identity (user). But with pairwise, each client will receive a different (yet fixed for that client) sub for the Identity. This should prevent that hosts from app1 and app2 can compare identities and create profiles based on the sub.

Comment: Ah, thank you, now I understand it all! That's a good thing to have, but it might lead to more confusions and/or inconsistencies. Imagine authenticating with your google account for 1 system - your subjectId will be 48 there, but you go in on another - and it will be 3003 there. if the 2 client apps ever wanted to collaborate, they'd have a hard time doing so because they don't have such an evident obvious way to validate 2 users. Although for many other cases, it's a great thing to have (if you don't need 2 client apps to communicate)

Comment: The sub claim itself doesn't have to be the exact value of the id, the only requirement is that it is unique within the authority. So you can hash it if you like or map it to a random but fixed guid. With an external provider you create a local user. Now you can use the value of the provider e.g. in combination with a prefix, something like google_48, instead of 3003, the local id. Or use the local id and and the original value as an additional claim.